# Editing Java source files

Tags: java

I am currently making a project, that has a username and password system which uses text files. To try and keep my project organized, they are within the same netbeans folder. However, the files that are there are under `src\classes\prototype1\textFiles` but the files being edited when I add a user are under `build\classes\prototype1\textFiles`. The problem this is causing is that whenever I re-launch netbeans, it goes only off the original data that I have in the `src` folder, and not the edited data from the `build` folder.

The code I used is:

```
try {
    File f = new File(getClass().getResource("textFiles\\PasswordScreen.txt").toURI());
    f.setWritable(true);
    FileWriter w = new FileWriter(f);
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(w);
    wipeFile(f);
    for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++){
        writer.write(user[i].getUsername());
        writer.newLine();
        writer.write(user[i].getPassword());
        writer.newLine();
        writer.write(Integer.toString(user[i].getState()));
        writer.newLine();
        writer.write("-");
        writer.newLine();
    }
    writer.close();
    f.setReadOnly();
} catch(Exception e){System.out.println("error writing to file");}
```

Comment: Anything under `src/` is purely Java code to be compiled. You should not place any resource files there.

Comment: Why are you editing a file in the `build` folder? Once you deploy you code in a .jar file, the file won't even *be* a file on the harddrive. Any file that you edit must be *outside* the app code hierarchy.

Comment: Resources should be considered read-only.  Applications are usually delivered as .jar files, in which case you won’t be able to write to the resource because it won’t be a separate file.  (Also, `getResource` uses forward slashes (`/`) as file separators, on all platforms; the argument is essentially a relative URL.)

Comment: As a side-note that is not directly related to the problem: **Do not** store user passwords in plain-text in a file somewhere, ever.

Comment: For an A-Level project is this not sufficent enough? The passwords are encrypted. Finally, how would you store it?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, I have never actually properly compiled my code as a .jar file (something else to figure out how to do), so I was unsure how it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mix of effects.

The file you are addressing is in the `classes` folder: This folder is the compiler's output folder. As such, it contains per definition volatile content, because the contents are created from the `src` folder.

When starting your IDE (NetBeans in this case), it will clean the project and rebuild the classes, overwriting your previously edited user settings.

The solution is simple: Do not write the edited file to the `classes` folder. Use another location, for example the current directory. This is usually the project root for IDE starts and can be properly controlled.

You may want to make the file's location configurable somewhere (commandline, environment variable, ...).

Comment: Thank you I will try this in the morning and report back then!